# embed games code uploaded in flash and silver light

Tags: php, zend-framework, embed

I need to embed games to my website. the games is being uploaded as flash and silver light AND I NEED TO GET THE SCORES AND PREFORM SO CALCULATION ON THEM can anyone help me to start doing such thing i am doing a research for a time now and cant find the piece of code for this, and i am using php and zend framework. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed flash into your website like this:

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-embed-flash-intro-html.html

and silverlight like this:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/22154/77925.aspx

Comment: and i need it to manage through this embeds can i do that or i need a special API for that

Comment: no you can't, but you could interact trough ajax calls and / or webservices for example

Comment: how do most of the gameing website handle there score then ??